# How to call a function once from Obserable.subscribe regardless if there are data or not in Angular RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, frontend

There is a observable that takes data from endpoint:

```
this.get().pipe(
  filter(item => item.id = providedId)
).subscribe((data) => {
  specialFunction(data);
})
```

When the filter method of RxJS finds an item, it fires subscribe and everything works as expected.
But when filter wont find item, subscribe is not fired. But i would like to handle this scenario also. I have tried to use complete:

```
this.get().pipe(
  filter(item => item.id = providedId)
).subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
       specialFunction(data);
    },
    complete: (data) => {
       specialFunction();
    }
})
```

But than, specialFunction is called twice if data is present: once with data, and once from completed function.

How to handle observable so i can call a specialFunction once, regardless if there are data or not, with data included if there are data?

Comment: deal with it on `complete` only and start your handler with `if (data) { ... }` ?

Comment: it is an idea, but how to pass data nicely from next to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter your data in your subscribe.

```
this.get().subscribe((data) => {
    const filteredData = data.filter(item => item.id = providedId);
    specialFunction(filteredData);
});


function specialFunction(data: any|undefined) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to use filter. Use a map and handle the match in subscribe:

```
this.get().pipe(
  map(item => { isMatch: item.id == providedId, item })
).subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
       if (data.isMatch) {
           specialFunction(data.item);
       } else {
          // handle non-match
       }
    },
    complete: (data) => {
       specialFunction();
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, actually there are multiple items that can satisfy the filter. i don't know if this will work that way

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't check your conditions inside rxjs `map` and return the truthy value if condition passes, and "something else" if not. But to throw out another option you could ...

Maybe use [`iif`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/iif.html):

> Subscribe to first or second observable based on a condition

So perhaps something like this:

```
import { of, iif } from "rxjs";
import { mergeMap, filter } from "rxjs/operators";

// ...

this.get()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(item =>
      iif(() => item.id === providedId
        // if truthy return this
        of(item),
        // if falsy, return null or whatever you like
        of(null)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      specialFunction(data);
    }
  });
```